# removal of adware go.deliverymodo.com

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android

I have Lenovo K4 note running on Android 5.1. This problem started today. Whenever I click on any page on chrome, the browser gets redirected to go.deliverymodo.com.

We have three smartphones and a laptop connected to the same wi-fi router, the problem is occurring  only on this one smartphone.

Have scanned the phone with Trend Micro, McAfee, Malewarebytes, and AVG antivrus Free Android security but none are able to identify / remove the adware.

Disabling JavaScript does prevent the redirection but then the regular links on the pages also do not work.

Can someone please suggest some tool that will resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you check if there's any malicious app installed in your device? Because there's no way *Google Chrome for Android* can be infected with adwares (like PCs). Did you try using different browsers?

Comment: Trying different browsers indeed is a good idea to narrow down the culprit. If they all show the same behavior, it's rather something intercepting your network traffic *on that device* (most likely the DNS, so all host names resolve to that site).

Comment: @Izzy Or a piece of malware that toyed with the hosts file.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman that would be toying with DNS while requiring root. Possible, yes. Also likely is some app that uses VPN functionality to reroute traffic. But that's all speculation without more facts :)

Comment: Have observed the same behaviour on UC Browser. Uninstalled and re-installed UC Browser but the problem persists. Checked DNS name on router -NETGEAR 2750U. It had been compromised but I set it back to the regular one. Two other devices  , Lenovo K3 and MOTO G4 plus, both having higher versions of Android , connected to the same router continue to work properly. I have not installed any new app, if something got installed by itself in the background then there could be a problem.

Comment: @Izzy I have done a factory reset but the problem still exists. I have deleted all the apps that I had downloaded, they were banking and e-commerce apps.

Comment: I have also tried using mobile data instead of wifi router but the results are the same.

Comment: Have also upgraded to android 6.0

Comment: Now things are getting weird: persisting after the factory-rest I could understand (some malware having managed to covert itself into a system app). But a system upgrade? What kind of upgrade was that: an OTA (just replacing some files), or a "clean flash" (wiping the entire system off before replacing it with a fresh install)? The latter should have killed even "system-app-malware", the former not necessarily.

Comment: @izzy I was running Android 5.1, and just went to settings->...system update and initiated update, it downloaded Marshmallow and upgraded to it, so effectively moved from lollipop to marshmallow. Planning to take it to service centre for clean install as I would not like to get into rooting myself.

Comment: That was an OTA then, and most likely didn't a "clean flash" – it just put itself on top of what was there. So if some malware converted itself into a system app, it was able to survive that. To really get rid of it, you'd need to do a full (clean) flash then. The K4 AFAIK is an MTK device, so you could use Flashtool (available cross-platform) and the matching ROM files to do so. I cannot tell you were to find the latter, though.

Comment: Looks like Onclick Functionality has been hijacked. Once I disable javascript, the problem doesn't surface. Unfortunately most of the sites that I access do not function properly with JavaScript disabled.